# How can I delete all items in a RealmResults list fastest and easiest?

Tags: java, android, realm, datastore

I have a line that returns a RealmResult with some sorted data.

I want to delete all these items the fastest and easiest. For example:

```
RealmResults<ElementEntry> currentElements = realm.where(ElementEntry.class).equalTo("type", 1).findAll();

//something like this then, would be preffered:
currentElements.removeFromRealm();
```

But I have to use iterators and what-not, but when I try that, I get this error:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: No outside changes to a Realm is allowed while iterating a RealmResults. Use iterators methods instead.
```

So what CAN I use, if not the very iterator that is supposed to be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the clear method

From the docs:

```
Removes all objects from the list. This also deletes the objects from the  underlying Realm.
@throws IllegalStateException if the corresponding Realm is closed or in an incorrect thread.
```

https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/realm-library/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmResults.java#L636

```
realm.beginTransaction();
currentElements.clear()
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: This is correct - found the "clear" method from this issue tracker too: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2061

Comment: Clear() is now depreciated, use deleteAllFromRealm() instead

Answer (score 2):

To delate all objects in a realmResults do that:

```
RealmResults<Dog> results = realm.where(Dog.class).findAll();

// All changes to data must happen in a transaction
realm.beginTransaction();
results.clear();
realm.commitTransaction()
```

To iterate you can do that:

```
realm.beginTransaction();
for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
  results.get(i).setProperty("foo");
}
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: Again, clear() is now depreciated on RealmResults use deleteAllFromRealm()

Comment: Okay, I am in Realm 2.8.3 and have the following code: `        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            try realm.write {
                var results = realm.objects(Category.self)
                results.removeAll()
                results.deleteAllFromRealm()
                results.clear()
            }
        } catch {}
` All three methods are not defined on the Results<> datatype. What is the *current* answer for this question?

Answer (score 2):

`clear()` is deprecated. You should use `deleteAllFromRealm()`.

**Delete the results of a query:**

```
final RealmResults<Dog> results = realm.where(Dog.class).findAll();

realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        // remove single match
        results.deleteFirstFromRealm();
        results.deleteLastFromRealm();

        // remove a single object
        Dog dog = results.get(5);
        dog.deleteFromRealm();

        // Delete all matches
        results.deleteAllFromRealm();
    }
});
```

**Delete all objects from Realm database:**

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        realm.deleteAll();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am using Realm 2.8.3 and have the following code:

```
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        try realm.write {
            var results = realm.objects(Category.self)
            results.removeAll()
            results.deleteAllFromRealm()
            results.clear()
        }
    } catch {}
```

All three methods are not defined on the Results<> datatype. What is the *current* answer for this question?